# Python __getattr__ called and enter infinite recursion even the attribute is not missing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

I define a `NE_Conv2d` class and override its `__getattr__`. When I try to get an existing attribute from one instance of this class, `__getattr__` is called and enter infinite recursion.

I know one need  to deal with `__getattr__` carefully to avoid infinite recursion, but apparently the `conv` attribute already exists after `__init__` is called. So when I try to get `conv` attribute, `__getattr__` should not be called.

```py
from torch import nn
class NE_Conv2d(nn.Module):
    '''Nonexpansive conv2d'''

    def __init__(self, *k, **kw):
        super(NE_Conv2d, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(*k, **kw)
        print('foo')

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.conv, attr)

a = NE_Conv2d(3, 32, 5)
print(a)
print(a.conv)
```

Above code should print info about `a` and `a.conv`, but enter infinite recursion when trying to get `a.conv`.

Comment: `__getattr__` is only called if an attribute (`conv` here) is not found on an object.  In this case `self.conv` is assigned in the `__init__` method so `__getattr__` will not be called if `a.conv` is accessed.

Comment: My thought is same as yours and that's the reason why I am totally confused when I run the above code and got `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to know what's wrong... `setattr` and `getattr` of `nn.Module` is reloaded...